# Class not found - PHP server config?

Tags: php

So I'm working from a laptop, and I'm developing a PHP application. Being allowed to work from home, I installed EasyPHP on the laptop so I can host the web application locally on the laptop and work even when not connected to the internet, and without the use for a VPN connection, and even for when I'm at work, no need to mess with FileZilla or whatever, everthing will be so much easier like that for me.

My problem is the following: from our dev server, at work, everything is good. I copied the whole code in my easyphp folder, and I make a duplicate of my database in my local MySQL server. Running the application on my work's dev server, everything is fine. But locally, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'ConfigNamespace' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\MyApplication\libs\config\ConfigParser.php on line 50`

So my ConfigParser class calls a New ConfigNamespace() at line 50... The local server doesn't like it. The ConfigNamespace class sits next to the ConfigParser class, in the \libs\config folder. Why does t not work locally, but works on the dev server?

I am under the impression that the configuration of the servers are different, and that my local server decides to expect all the classes to be in the root folder... but it's not!

I've searched on the web but only found things regarding system classes being unreachable... nothing that really has anything to do with my problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Server configuration has nothing to do with this kind of errors. Check your code.

Comment: The code works on one server and doesn't on the other. The code should be fine...

Comment: Did you `include_once()` the file that contains ConfigNamespace or are you using class autoloading?

Comment: Well, I can write a fila that opens `C:\Pictures\apples.jpg` in my PC and it won't work in yours.

Comment: Either it's not namespace properly, or you're missing some PSR-4 configuration. Does the project use composer? If so, you may need to run `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: if you are runnig your server really under `C:\Program Files (x86)\` is possbile a problem with rights

Comment: I'm interested into the autoloading thing giraff is talking about. Care to give me more info?

Alvaro, please. This is not the same thing. The SERVER is the only thing that changed. Not the code. I'm not trying to reach a class that is not there. My class IS there, correctly nammed and in the correct folder.

Comment: I thought about it too aynber, but I made sure I had full permissions, and the code clearly runs a couple of files before I get this error... I still don't rule this out completely, but I did give the folder all permissions needed, and I am administrator of my machine :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It ended up being a problem with rights on the folders after all. I did give it all the rights, but windows somehow still blocked it... I changed my document root for another folder, not in program files, and now everything works!